# redirecciono pero no logro mostrar los títulos de el departamento seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

muy buenas a todos, tengo una duda con respecto al siguiente código, en el cual la primera función me lista los departamentos en los cuales puedo hacer clic, al seleccionar dicho departamento me tendría que redireccionar y mostrar todos los títulos de el departamento seleccionado, a nivel de MySQL ya lo hice, pero a nivel de código me redirecciona, pero no me muestra los títulos, alguien me podría ayudar en decirme cual es mi error o como hacerlo de mejor forma.de ante mano muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

```
function cargar_departamentos() {

var departamentos = {
    "accion": 'Departamentos_disponibles',
    "id_publicacion":"",
    "detalle_id":"",
    "categoria_id":"",
    "usuario_id":"",
    "departamento_id":"",
    "publicacion_titulo":"",
    "publicacion_subtitulo":"",
    "publicacion_descripcion":"",
    "publicacion_votos":"",
    "publicacion_vistas":"",
    "estado_id":""
};
$("#img_carga").css("display", "block");

$.ajax({
    url: url_departamento,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(departamentos),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        const array = data;
        let listado = '';
        // console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            listado += '<li class="epkb-article-level-1 " style="padding-bottom: 8px; padding-top: 8px;">' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="redireccionar(' + array[i].id_departamento + ')" class="epkb-mp-article">' +
            '<span class="eckb-article-title" style="color: #606060;">' +
            '<span class="eckb-article-title__icon ep_font_icon_document" style="color: #525252;" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
            '<span class="eckb-article-title__text">' + array[i].Departamentos + '</span>' +
            '</span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>';
        }
        $("#comenzar").append(listado);    
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error al cargar los departamentos');
        $("#img_carga").css("display", "none");
    },
    complete: function() {
        $("#img_carga").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

};

```
function redireccionar(idDepartamento) {
 console.log(idDepartamento);

var parametros = {
    "accion":'consultar_titulos',
    "id_publicacion":"",
    "detalle_id":"",
    "categoria_id":"",
    "usuario_id":"",
    "departamento_id":idDepartamento,
    "publicacion_titulo":"",
    "publicacion_subtitulo":"",
    "publicacion_descripcion":"",
    "publicacion_votos":"",
    "publicacion_vistas":"",
    "estado_id":""
};
 
$.ajax({
    url: url_titulos,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        // Limpiar el contenedor donde se mostrarán los títulos
        $("#titulos_departamento").empty();
        console.log(data);
        // Iterar sobre los títulos y agregarlos al contenedor
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Agregar un enlace <a> con un evento onclick para redireccionar a otra página
            $("#titulos_departamento").append("<li><a href='Titulos?id=" + data[i].idDepartamento + "'>" + data[i].Titulos + "</a></li>");
        }
        debugger
        // Redireccionar después de haber agregado los títulos, pero no me los muestra los titulos
        window.location.href = 'Titulos?id=' + idDepartamento;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error al cargar los títulos');
    }
});
```

};

Comment: ¿Inspeccionaste el DOM, por si haya algo mal concatenado?

Comment: si, lo que me llama la atención es que cuando tengo el listado de los departamento y ahí reviso en console, si tengo los títulos de el departamento seleccionado, cuando ya me redirecciona entonces ahí ya pierdo los títulos.

Comment: No me refería a lo que hay en consola, sino a lo que se está renderizando en tu HTML. Por cierto, ¿cuál es la idea de "redireccionar"? Porque suena a que estás queriendo mostrar los datos en una página nueva.

Comment: si, la idea es la siguiente, tengo una pagina que muestra los departamentos, si yo selecciono en X departamento, me mostrara una nueva pagina con los títulos de el departamento seleccionado, lo cual si lo hace, pero no me muestra los títulos, es como si no los imprimiera en la pagina nueva. si necesita algo mas con gusto le explico mas a fondo.

Comment: Ya comprendí lo que hacés. Ahora: ¿Qué HTML debería cargarse cuando vas a la URL `'Titulos?id=' + idDepartamento`? La carga debés hacerla estando en la nueva página (no antes), o en todo caso utilizá persistencia de JS, y recuperá los datos desde allí.

Comment: buscare info sobre la persistencia, y creo que el redireccionamiento lo estoy haciendo mal. tratare de buscar otra solución.